# How to install "WST Server Adapter Plug-in Developer Resources" for eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I tried to do some web search and also go to Eclipse marketplace, but I couldn't find this package.

I also tried to go to the [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/), but I couldn't find this package. All I find is the `WST Server Adapter` package.

Answer (score 0):

For Developer Resources and SDKs, you need the specific project's update site: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/ .

Comment: thanks - I was there but I still couldn't find the "WST Server Adapter Plug-in Developer Resource" package. I can see the "WST Server Adapter" package there though.